# Can GoT's dragons run out of fire?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I don't know so much about dragons, especially Game of Thrones's dragons, but the amount of fire dragon breathed in `S08E05` seemed unreal to me, even for that magical dragon. So, was it logical in the Game of Thrones world?

Comment: Sorry, unlimited mana.

Comment: I guess that for a dragon, fire is like saliva for humans: something its body keeps producing 24/7. All it takes then is proper feeding, which is likely done in the short periods of time when the dragon does not breathe fire and we can see it flying away. (Just to return shortly after for more rounds)

Comment: CheatCode: HESOYAM, UZUMYMW, JUMPJET

Comment: In reality, Most dragons don't breath fire, however. Some dragons used to polish their teeth on certain rocks which had flammable material, which caused them to breathe fire when they exhaled when chewing food.

Answer (score 19):

Dragons have as much fire as the writers need them to have. So far, there has been no indication that it runs out, has a cooldown or something similar.

Comment: The power of plot, similar to Superman's wildly varying power levels

Comment: Can it explained based on the book? I mean in the book can dragons run out of fire?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Not that I know of. A similar attack was made during Aegon's Conquest on Harrenhall, melting it's towers to the ruins it is now. No mention is made that Balerion was at its limits or something like that.

Comment: I've always assumed the fire is generated by two separated glands with binary components for an incendiary compound, which would be how a dragon could hold that fire within and produce fire only once it leaves their mouths, or if they are injured (gland or bladder gets ruptured and leaks).  That would suggest they could run out, hypothetically, but I guess my theories will never get tested.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet The explanation is simple: they're magic.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Also noted when the Night's King spears Viserion there's a fiery explosion coming out of the wound. There was none when Euron Greyjoy gets Rhaegal, though.

Comment: @Inkblot - same for when Rhaegal wounds dead-Viserion.

Comment: When they need lots of fire like the huge amount of fire we see at the gates of King's Landing in 8x5, they have no problem.  Yet when they need some dramatic tension, like when Drogon is being swarmed by wights in 8x3, he can only swish his tail and make noise rather than blasting fire at any of the approaching wights.